# Why when we convert the sum log probabilities to integral we multiply with $P_r$

Tags: probability

\begin{aligned}
    \lim_{m \to \infty}
    \max_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \log P_\theta(x^{(i)})
    &= \max_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d} \int_x P_r(x) \log P_\theta(x) \, dx \\
\end{aligned}

A [screenshot](https://www.alexirpan.com/2017/02/22/wasserstein-gan.html) showing more context:
[image: https://www.alexirpan.com/2017/02/22/wasserstein-gan.html]

Comment: There's a whole bunch of notation here that you need to explain. Some of it's reasonably obvious, like $\theta$ is a parameter vector and $P_\theta$ is presumably a density for some parameter values, but what even is $P_r$? And is the $x^{(i)}$ a sample or some fixed infinite vector?